# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ParentContainer'

Tags: python, attributeerror, pysimplegui

I am a beginner to python and am working PySimpleGUI and I keep getting this error and can't figure out why. Help is welcome...

There error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/georgeknight/pythonProject/Metrics.py", line 17, in <module>
[tm_number], [sg.Column(col1)], [sg.Column(col2)],
  File "/Users/georgeknight/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 7811, in __init__
self.Layout(layout)
  File "/Users/georgeknight/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 7893, in layout
self.AddRow(*row)
  File "/Users/georgeknight/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 7851, in add_row
    if element.ParentContainer is not None:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ParentContainer'
```

Here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

tm_number = sg.Text("Technical Manual Number:",  font=(24,24)),
            sg.Input(key='tm_number', font=(24,24), size=(48,24))
review = sg.Text("Type of Review:",  font=(24,24)),
         sg.Input(key='review', font=(24,24), size=(12,24))
pages = sg.Text("Number of Pages: ",  font=(24,24)),
        sg.Input(key='pages', font=(24,24), size=(6,24))
submission_date = sg.Text("Date of Submission: ",  font=(24,24)),
                  sg.Input(key='submission_date', font=(24,24), size=(12,24))
writer = sg.Text("Writer's Name: ",  font=(24,24)),
         sg.Input(key='writer', font=(24,24), size=(24,24))
col1 = [[review], [submission_date]]
col2 = [[writer], [pages]]

layout = [[sg.Text("Writer's Submission Form", font=(48,48))],
          [tm_number], [sg.Column(col1), sg.Column(col2)],
          [sg.Button("SUBMIT FOR REVIEW", size=(24,1), font=24)]]

window = sg.Window("Technical Manual Engineering Review (TMER)", layout)

event, values = window.read()

window.close
```

I am trying to build a simple GUI with the variable "tm_number" at the top and then 2 columns: one column with variable "review" and "submission_date" and the other with "writer" and "pages". The button should be in the bottom right hand corner of the window (haven't gotten that far yet).

Comment: Commas don't automatically perform line continuation. You're making one-element tuples and discarding all the `sg.Input(...)`s.

Answer (score 0):

```py
c = a, b    # c = (a, b)
d = [c]     # d = [(a, b)], not [a, b]
```

Check if the format for a layout is in `List[List[Element]] | Tuple[Tuple[Element]]`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

tm_number       = [sg.Text("Technical Manual Number:",  font=(24,24)), sg.Input(key='tm_number', font=(24,24), size=(48,24))]
review          = [sg.Text("Type of Review:",  font=(24,24)), sg.Input(key='review', font=(24,24), size=(12,24))]
pages           = [sg.Text("Number of Pages: ",  font=(24,24)), sg.Input(key='pages', font=(24,24), size=(6,24))]
submission_date = [sg.Text("Date of Submission: ",  font=(24,24)),sg.Input(key='submission_date', font=(24,24), size=(12,24))]
writer          = [sg.Text("Writer's Name: ",  font=(24,24)), sg.Input(key='writer', font=(24,24), size=(24,24))]
col1            = [review, submission_date]
col2            = [writer, pages]

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Writer's Submission Form", font=(48,48))],
     tm_number,
    [sg.Column(col1), sg.Column(col2)],
    [sg.Button("SUBMIT FOR REVIEW", size=(24,1), font=24)],
]
window = sg.Window("Technical Manual Engineering Review (TMER)", layout).read(close=True)
```

Comment: I had the script working up until I added the sg.Column methods. That is what I am trying to figure out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason did, define the columns as such:

```py
col1 = [review, submission_date]
col2 = [writer, pages]
```

Remove the extra brackets and the program executes, you might have to twiddle to get the formatting/spacing correct.